# Firebase Authentication - Sign in error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to sign in using Firebase Authentication with the following code:

```
 _signInWithPopup: function() {
     var auth = this.$.auth;
     var that = this;

     var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

     app.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
         console.log(result);
         console.log("User has signed in");
     }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error);
     })
 },
```

It redirects to a blank screen and I'm then presented with all of these errors.
Has anyone seen this before? What's happening here? The code is literally copy and paste from the docs.

```
polymer-micro.html:1 Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'dom-module'. A type with that name is already registered.(anonymous function) @ polymer-micro.html:1(anonymous function) @ polymer-micro.html:1
polymer-micro.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.Base._getExtendedPrototype is not a functiont @ polymer-micro.html:1window.Polymer @ polymer-micro.html:1(anonymous function) @ polymer.html:7(anonymous function) @ polymer.html:7
polymer-micro.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: this._desugarBehaviors is not a functionregisterCallback @ polymer-micro.html:1t @ polymer-micro.html:1window.Polymer @ polymer-micro.html:1(anonymous function) @ user-manager.html:5(anonymous function) @ user-manager.html:5
polymer-micro.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: this._desugarBehaviors is not a functionregisterCallback @ polymer-micro.html:1t @ polymer-micro.html:1window.Polymer @ polymer-micro.html:1(anonymous function) @ user-manager.html:9
polymer-micro.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: this._desugarBehaviors is not a functionregisterCallback @ polymer-micro.html:1t @ polymer-micro.html:1window.Polymer @ polymer-micro.html:1(anonymous function) @ user-manager.html:30
polymer.html:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dashToCamelCase' of undefined_parseNodeAttributeAnnotation @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAttributeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseElementAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseChildNodesAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseElementAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5parseAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_prepAnnotations @ my-app.html:45_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
polymer-micro.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: this._desugarBehaviors is not a functionregisterCallback @ polymer-micro.html:1t @ polymer-micro.html:1window.Polymer @ polymer-micro.html:1(anonymous function) @ polymerfire.html:59(anonymous function) @ polymerfire.html:59
polymer-micro.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: this._desugarBehaviors is not a functionregisterCallback @ polymer-micro.html:1t @ polymer-micro.html:1window.Polymer @ polymer-micro.html:1(anonymous function) @ polymerfire.html:80
polymerfire.html:84 Uncaught ReferenceError: UserManager is not defined(anonymous function) @ polymerfire.html:84
polymer.html:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dashToCamelCase' of undefined_parseNodeAttributeAnnotation @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAttributeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseElementAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseChildNodesAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseElementAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5parseAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_prepAnnotations @ my-app.html:45_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15instanceTemplate @ my-app.html:29_stampTemplate @ my-app.html:29_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
my-app.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'camelToDashCase' of undefined_addPropertyEffects @ my-app.html:45_prepBehavior @ my-app.html:47_prepFlattenedBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_prepBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15instanceTemplate @ my-app.html:29_stampTemplate @ my-app.html:29_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
polymer.html:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dashToCamelCase' of undefined_parseNodeAttributeAnnotation @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAttributeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseElementAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseChildNodesAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseElementAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5parseAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_prepAnnotations @ my-app.html:45_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15instanceTemplate @ my-app.html:29_stampTemplate @ my-app.html:29_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
my-app.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'camelToDashCase' of undefined_addPropertyEffects @ my-app.html:45_prepBehavior @ my-app.html:47_prepFlattenedBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_prepBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15instanceTemplate @ my-app.html:29_stampTemplate @ my-app.html:29_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
my-app.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'camelToDashCase' of undefined_addPropertyEffects @ my-app.html:45_prepBehavior @ my-app.html:47_prepFlattenedBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_prepBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15instanceTemplate @ my-app.html:29_stampTemplate @ my-app.html:29_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
my-app.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'camelToDashCase' of undefined_addPropertyEffects @ my-app.html:45_prepBehavior @ my-app.html:47_prepFlattenedBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_prepBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15instanceTemplate @ my-app.html:29_stampTemplate @ my-app.html:29_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
my-app.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'camelToDashCase' of undefined_addPropertyEffects @ my-app.html:45_prepBehavior @ my-app.html:47_prepFlattenedBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_prepBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15instanceTemplate @ my-app.html:29_stampTemplate @ my-app.html:29_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
polymer.html:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dashToCamelCase' of undefined_parseNodeAttributeAnnotation @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAttributeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseElementAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseChildNodesAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseElementAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_parseNodeAnnotations @ polymer.html:5parseAnnotations @ polymer.html:5_prepAnnotations @ my-app.html:45_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15instanceTemplate @ my-app.html:29_stampTemplate @ my-app.html:29_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
my-app.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'camelToDashCase' of undefined_addPropertyEffects @ my-app.html:45_prepBehavior @ my-app.html:47_prepFlattenedBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_prepBehaviors @ my-app.html:15_finishRegisterFeatures @ my-app.html:47_ensureRegisterFinished @ my-app.html:15createdCallback @ my-app.html:15instanceTemplate @ my-app.html:29_stampTemplate @ my-app.html:29_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
my-app.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined_marshalIdNodes @ my-app.html:45_marshalAnnotationReferences @ my-app.html:45_initFeatures @ my-app.html:47createdCallback @ my-app.html:15
polymer-micro.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: this._desugarBehaviors is not a functionregisterCallback @ polymer-micro.html:1t @ polymer-micro.html:1window.Polymer @ polymer-micro.html:1(anonymous function) @ iframe?apiKey=AIzaSyBPlIeqSbYiQ5cp1dV89OoDKrns605WyPI&appName=test&v=3.3.1&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2…:59(anonymous function) @ iframe?apiKey=AIzaSyBPlIeqSbYiQ5cp1dV89OoDKrns605WyPI&appName=test&v=3.3.1&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2…:59
polymer-micro.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: this._desugarBehaviors is not a functionregisterCallback @ polymer-micro.html:1t @ polymer-micro.html:1window.Polymer @ polymer-micro.html:1(anonymous function) @ iframe?apiKey=AIzaSyBPlIeqSbYiQ5cp1dV89OoDKrns605WyPI&appName=test&v=3.3.1&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2…:80
iframe?apiKey=AIzaSyBPlIeqSbYiQ5cp1dV89OoDKrns605WyPI&appName=test&v=3.3.1&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2…:84 Uncaught ReferenceError: UserManager is not defined(anonymous function) @ iframe?apiKey=AIzaSyBPlIeqSbYiQ5cp1dV89OoDKrns605WyPI&appName=test&v=3.3.1&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2…:84
user-manager.html:259 R {code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}
firebase.js:167 Uncaught Error: Network Error(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:167
```

Comment: Try to run this code on other browser. This looks like polymer is facing some problem. I had written tutorial for understanding auth with Google firebase http://time2hack.com/2016/06/auth-schemes-in-google-firebase.html. I hope it helps you understanding the auth with Firebase.

Comment: It works in Firefox but not Chrome or Safari

Comment: I think it can be problem with the version. I would recommend to use the latest version of firebase js. Try your code on some other system. This would ensure that your code is working fine across all browsers; only ptoblem is in the chrome/safari on your system. And for the time being continue testing it on firefox.